# appropriate HTTP status code for non-existent resources in REST API?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I am engineering a REST API server application, trying to establish a rule for the server response when a resource does not exist. While we can define our internal codes within our team, there is a controversy regarding the HTTP status code.

Consider an endpoint POST /a (body: { "bid": 123 }). This endpoint is for creating a user-owned 'a' resource. During creation, a 'b' resource is needed, so the id of 'b' is included in the body as a payload. However, if there is no resource with id=123 in 'b', should this be treated as 404 Not Found?

I would appreciate your insights from both the principles of REST and conventions. It would be even better if you could provide references to official documents like RFC.

currently I chose 404 not found. But my team says it is wrong. What is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, if there is no resource with id=123 in 'b', should this be treated as 404 Not Found?

Probably not.

Key idea: HTTP status codes are metadata of the [transfer-documents-over-a-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain, they are there to describe the nature of the response to general purpose components (browsers, proxies, and so on) so that those components can do interesting things.

---

In the case you describe, there is certainly a problem in the request, so some 4xx client error is appropriate.

[404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-404-not-found), however, indicates that the target resource does not have a current representation.  The [target resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#target.resource) is the resource identified by the request-target in the [request-line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9112.html#name-request-line).

Put simply, to send a 404 response is to imply that the HTTP request had a spelling error in the URI of the requested resource.

In your example:

```
POST /a HTTP/1.1
```

the target resource is that resource identified by `/a`.  And that part of the message is correct: the spelling of the request-target does match the identifier of your request processor; therefore a 404 response is misleading.

What you want is one of the [registered](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) status codes that implicate the request *body*, rather than the request *target*.

[422 Unprocessable Content](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-422-unprocessable-content) is a better fit.

Comment: Thanks. It's very clear. The youtube, RFC document and your advice would be so helpful